# How to increase array length? value too long for type character varying(255)

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony

Is it possible to increase the length of an array?

I have tried adding `length: 2048` and re-created the migrations (deleted migrations, dropped db, created db, and created new migration). It shows as `missing_deposit_dates TEXT DEFAULT NULL`

Running Symfony 6, PHP 8.2, PostgreSQL.

Column

```
#[ORM\Column(type: 'array', length: 2048, nullable: true)]
private ?array $missingDepositDates = [];
```

Exception

> An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[22001]: String
> data, right truncated: 7 ERROR: value too long for type character
> varying(255)

Comment: These records should be in a separate table, one record per row, foreign-keyed to the id of this table, and defined as a One-To-Many relationship in Doctrine. Then it doesn't matter how many you have and you won't continually be coming back here to bump the size because that one problematic entry surpassed 2K. See [1NF](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/first-normal-form-1nf/).

Comment: This does not look like a PHP related problem to me

Answer (score 2):

It is setting your property as TEXT because the attribute `length` only applies to string columns. [Doctrine property mapping](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/current/reference/basic-mapping.html#property-mapping)

There is no size limit on PostgreSQL arrays. This will make your ***make:migration*** command pass successfully:

```
#[ORM\Column(nullable: true)]
private ?array $missingDepositDates = [];
```

To limit the array length I would do it when I persist the changes of the entity in my PHP code. You could validate if the length of the current array is less than 2048 before persisting the changes.